# not able to add jar in linux server while executing java class

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I am executing 2 java classes which have StringUtils function. For this I have  common-lang3.jar  so I am giving command

```
`javac -cp  common-lang3.jar *.java`
```

this time no error but after that

`java -cp  common-lang3.jar  abc.class` its giving
 `Could not find or load main class`  For linux server where I have to place jar files so that i can just give command javac *.java ? If in classpath java -classpath is not allowing me to edit. pls help

Comment: Hint: read about the java class path. This is really **basic** stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
java -cp  common-lang3.jar  abc.class
```

to (assuming abc has your `main` method)

```
java -cp  common-lang3.jar:.  abc
```

Comment: thanks working  everytime i have to compile like this or any permanent adding place is there ? like in environment variavle java classpath ?

Comment: `export CLASSPATH="common-lang3.jar:."` is one such alternative. I suggest you review [PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) from the Java Tutorials.